# NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays angular8

Tags: angular

I want to recover the data from github and display these data, but it gives me error. Editor code underline this.followers in file github-followers.component.ts .

**githup-followers.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let follower of followers" class="media">
    <div class="media-left">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="avatar media-object" src="{{ follower.avatar_url }}">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**githup-followers.component.ts**

```
constructor(private service:GithubFollowersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAll()
    .subscribe(followers => this.followers = followers);
  }
```

**githup-followers.service.ts**

```
export class GithubFollowersService extends DataService {

  constructor(http:Http) {
    super('https://api.github.com/users/IDBRAHIMDEV/followers',http)
   }
```

**data.service.ts**

```
  constructor(private url : string ,private http : Http) { }

  getAll(){
    return this.http.get(this.url).
    pipe(
      catchError(
        this.handleError
      )   
    )}
```

Comment: What is this.followers *before* the request finishes?

Comment: ... and isn't this basically a duplicate of what you asked just a while ago? ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58061727/cannot-find-a-differ-supporting-object-response-with-status-200 You really actually shouldn't ask duplicates, please.

Comment: it's a array declare in githup-followers.component.ts

Comment: But does it have a *value*? Give an actual [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use *ngIf :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="followers?.length > 0">
<div *ngFor="let follower of followers" class="media">
    <div class="media-left">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="avatar media-object" src="{{ follower.avatar_url }}">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: If `followers` is null / undefined, testing `followers.length > 0` will already cause error. Will work with the safe access operator: `followers?.length > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `followers` is an array *when the request completes*, the only problem is that you're trying to iterate over undefined until the HTTP call comes back with result. Initialize it to an empty array:

```
followers = [];

constructor(private service:GithubFollowersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAll()
    .subscribe(followers => this.followers = followers);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize followers:

this.followers = []

Answer (score 0):

Variable **this.followers** is probably not an **Array** but **Object**.

You can still iterate via Object.keys() method like this:

**random.template.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let follower of getKeys(this.followers)">

</div>
```

**random.component.ts**

```
  getKeys(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj);
  }
```

Also it is good idea to wrap whole *ngFor in *ngIf in case that this.followers is null or undefined.

```
<div *ngIf="this.followers">
    <div *ngFor="let follower of getKeys(this.followers)">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change Your code**

> in your service add this
>       constructor(private http : Http) { }

```
getAll(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get<any>(your api endpoint);
}
```

> and in your component subscribe to this service  The Error Clearly Tells That follower 
>   is not an array first declare Empty array

```
follower = [];
constructor(private service:Your servicename) { }
ngOnInit() {
this.service.getAll()
.subscribe(
            response => { this.follower = response },
            error => { console.log(error)
});
```